# javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException when trying cipher.doFinal() on android 12

Tags: android, encryption, keystore

When I try to run this code:

```
    PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_ALIAS, null);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION_RSA);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

    return cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
```

On this line(return cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes)) I get this exception: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException(cause = android.security.KeyStoreException: -69).

I get this exceptions only when I run app on device with android api 31, but for previous api it works correctly.

I attached an image of debugger info for this code.

[image: I attached an image of debugger info for this code.]

Log info:

```
    2022-06-11 19:36:41.590 702-10084/? E/libnos_datagram: can't send spi message: Try again
2022-06-11 19:36:41.596 702-10084/? E/libnos_datagram: can't send spi message: Try again
2022-06-11 19:36:41.601 702-10084/? E/libnos_datagram: can't send spi message: Try again
2022-06-11 19:36:41.607 702-10084/? E/libnos_datagram: can't send spi message: Try again
2022-06-11 19:36:41.613 702-10084/? E/libnos_datagram: can't send spi message: Try again
2022-06-11 19:36:41.710 703-703/? E/android.hardware.keymaster@4.1-service.citadel: UpdateOperation : device response error code: PROOF_OF_PRESENCE_REQUIRED
2022-06-11 19:36:41.710 735-764/? E/keystore2: keystore2::error: In KeystoreOperation::update
    
    Caused by:
        0: In update: KeyMint::update failed.
        1: Error::Km(ErrorCode(-69))
2022-06-11 19:36:41.727 703-703/? E/android.hardware.keymaster@4.1-service.citadel: UpdateOperation : device response error code: PROOF_OF_PRESENCE_REQUIRED
2022-06-11 19:36:41.727 735-763/? E/keystore2: keystore2::error: In KeystoreOperation::update
    
    Caused by:
        0: In update: KeyMint::update failed.
        1: Error::Km(ErrorCode(-69))
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment: io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred. 
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.common.ZipUtils.lambda$zip$0(ZipUtils.java:33)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.common.ZipUtils$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.apply(Unknown Source:4)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap$SingleFlatMapCallback.onSuccess(SingleFlatMap.java:76)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleZipArray$ZipCoordinator.innerSuccess(SingleZipArray.java:119)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleZipArray$ZipSingleObserver.onSuccess(SingleZipArray.java:170)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleOnErrorReturn$OnErrorReturn.onError(SingleOnErrorReturn.java:72)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleMap$MapSingleObserver.onError(SingleMap.java:69)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.onError(SingleSubscribeOn.java:73)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate$Emitter.tryOnError(SingleCreate.java:94)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate$Emitter.onError(SingleCreate.java:80)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.sdk.action.UnLockAction.lambda$unLock$1$UnLockAction(UnLockAction.java:76)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.sdk.action.UnLockAction$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.subscribe(Unknown Source:4)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate.subscribeActual(SingleCreate.java:39)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:   ComposedException 1 :
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:   javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:613)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2055)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.encryption.KeyStoreRsaEncryptionManager.decryptRSA(KeyStoreRsaEncryptionManager.java:152)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.covrvault.VaultImpl.generateShard(VaultImpl.java:162)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.covrvault.VaultImpl.generateSeed(VaultImpl.java:143)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.covrvault.VaultImpl.initStorage(VaultImpl.java:133)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.sdk.storage.StaticalEncryptedStorageProviderImpl.initStorage(StaticalEncryptedStorageProviderImpl.java:73)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.sdk.action.UnLockAction.lambda$unLock$0$UnLockAction(UnLockAction.java:49)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.sdk.action.UnLockAction$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.subscribe(Unknown Source:2)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate.subscribeActual(SingleCreate.java:39)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.747 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:   Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: -69
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at android.security.KeyStore2.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore2.java:356)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at android.security.KeyStoreOperation.handleExceptions(KeyStoreOperation.java:78)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at android.security.KeyStoreOperation.update(KeyStoreOperation.java:114)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer$MainDataStream.update(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:222)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.update(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:156)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:179)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:603)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2055)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.encryption.KeyStoreRsaEncryptionManager.decryptRSA(KeyStoreRsaEncryptionManager.java:152)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.covrvault.VaultImpl.generateShard(VaultImpl.java:162)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.covrvault.VaultImpl.generateSeed(VaultImpl.java:143)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.covrvault.VaultImpl.initStorage(VaultImpl.java:133)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.sdk.storage.StaticalEncryptedStorageProviderImpl.initStorage(StaticalEncryptedStorageProviderImpl.java:73)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.sdk.action.UnLockAction.lambda$unLock$0$UnLockAction(UnLockAction.java:49)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.sdk.action.UnLockAction$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.subscribe(Unknown Source:2)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate.subscribeActual(SingleCreate.java:39)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:   ComposedException 2 :
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:   javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:613)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2055)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.encryption.KeyStoreRsaEncryptionManager.decryptRSA(KeyStoreRsaEncryptionManager.java:152)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.covrvault.VaultImpl.generateShard(VaultImpl.java:162)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.covrvault.VaultImpl.generateSeed(VaultImpl.java:143)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.covrvault.VaultImpl.initStorage(VaultImpl.java:133)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.sdk.storage.PinEncryptedStorageProviderImpl.initStorage(PinEncryptedStorageProviderImpl.java:79)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.sdk.action.UnLockAction.lambda$unLock$1$UnLockAction(UnLockAction.java:66)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.sdk.action.UnLockAction$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.subscribe(Unknown Source:4)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate.subscribeActual(SingleCreate.java:39)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:   Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: -69
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at android.security.KeyStore2.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore2.java:356)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at android.security.KeyStoreOperation.handleExceptions(KeyStoreOperation.java:78)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at android.security.KeyStoreOperation.update(KeyStoreOperation.java:114)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer$MainDataStream.update(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:222)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.update(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:156)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:179)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:603)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2055)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.encryption.KeyStoreRsaEncryptionManager.decryptRSA(KeyStoreRsaEncryptionManager.java:152)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.covrvault.VaultImpl.generateShard(VaultImpl.java:162)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.covrvault.VaultImpl.generateSeed(VaultImpl.java:143)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.covrvault.VaultImpl.initStorage(VaultImpl.java:133)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.sdk.storage.PinEncryptedStorageProviderImpl.initStorage(PinEncryptedStorageProviderImpl.java:79)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.sdk.action.UnLockAction.lambda$unLock$1$UnLockAction(UnLockAction.java:66)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at com.covrsecurity.io.sdk.action.UnLockAction$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.subscribe(Unknown Source:4)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate.subscribeActual(SingleCreate.java:39)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.748 15701-15701/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken E/LockScreenFragment:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
2022-06-11 19:36:41.758 2309-2309/? E/ndroid.systemu: Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~07SAFqSRPitbX4fcRSE5Rg==/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken-LVo_BnBuuwSVOm_qhNbg_w==/base.apk': I/O error
2022-06-11 19:36:41.759 2309-2309/? E/ndroid.systemu: Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~07SAFqSRPitbX4fcRSE5Rg==/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken-LVo_BnBuuwSVOm_qhNbg_w==/base.apk': I/O error
2022-06-11 19:36:41.759 2309-2309/? E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path '/data/app/~~07SAFqSRPitbX4fcRSE5Rg==/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken-LVo_BnBuuwSVOm_qhNbg_w==/base.apk'
    java.io.IOException: Failed to load asset path /data/app/~~07SAFqSRPitbX4fcRSE5Rg==/com.bangkokbank.sittxbtoken-LVo_BnBuuwSVOm_qhNbg_w==/base.apk
        at android.content.res.ApkAssets.nativeLoad(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.ApkAssets.<init>(ApkAssets.java:295)
        at android.content.res.ApkAssets.loadFromPath(ApkAssets.java:144)
        at android.app.ResourcesManager.loadApkAssets(ResourcesManager.java:454)
        at android.app.ResourcesManager.access$000(ResourcesManager.java:72)
        at android.app.ResourcesManager$ApkAssetsSupplier.load(ResourcesManager.java:168)
        at android.app.ResourcesManager.createAssetManager(ResourcesManager.java:530)
        at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResourcesImpl(ResourcesManager.java:612)
        at android.app.ResourcesManager.findOrCreateResourcesImplForKeyLocked(ResourcesManager.java:664)
        at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResources(ResourcesManager.java:1011)
        at android.app.ResourcesManager.getResources(ResourcesManager.java:1114)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:2376)
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1751)
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1737)
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1506)
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadUnbadgedItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:3029)
        at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadUnbadgedIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:290)
        at com.android.systemui.toast.SystemUIToast.getBadgedIcon(SystemUIToast.java:284)
        at com.android.systemui.toast.SystemUIToast.inflateToastView(SystemUIToast.java:198)
        at com.android.systemui.toast.SystemUIToast.<init>(SystemUIToast.java:90)
        at com.android.systemui.toast.SystemUIToast.<init>(SystemUIToast.java:77)
        at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastFactory.createToast(ToastFactory.java:78)
        at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastUI.lambda$showToast$0(ToastUI.java:113)
        at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastUI.$r8$lambda$w_gPCh3F8Xxn1jN4lkQZoUci71c(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastUI$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:16)
        at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastUI.showToast(ToastUI.java:140)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.CommandQueue$H.handleMessage(CommandQueue.java:1431)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Comment: When asking a question about an thrown Exception please always include the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: I assume by "only on android api 31" means that it only happens if you run your code on a device with Android 31? Do you use the same 2048 bit RSA key on all test devices or are they generated (and thus unique) on every device?

Comment: Robert, RSA keys are generated (and thus unique) on every device

Comment: Is it possible that you tried to decrypt data with the wrong RSA key? In RSA the encrypted value has to be smaller than the size of the modulus. It looks like your RSA was generated as 2048bit - but the actual key is because usually a few bits smaller. If the key is wrong it may be the case that the wrong key is a bit smaller (in bits) than the encrypted data which triggers this error. If the key is correct I don't know why you get this error.

Comment: I have a bitLength of a modulus = 2049. Can it help to find the reason of the issue?

Comment: 2049 are you sure? Common would be 2048.

Comment: I have different debugger info in my two devices(the first is android 10, the second is android 12). In android 10 all works correctly, but on android 12 I have this issue. Maybe I should show you images of debugger info of my two devices?

Comment: Hi @MihailMalahov , were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and got a better idea of what was wrong by printing the [getNumericErrorCode()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyStoreException#getNumericErrorCode()) result. You can then check this number with the [KeyStoreException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyStoreException) error codes to get a clearer error message.

For me I had an error code 2 after returning the getNumericErrorCode(), but in the logging of the exception itself it said -26.